# Results of Rotate and Translate are not the same in 2D and 3D

Tags: graphics3d, geometric-transform

I cannot understand why the same transformations in 2D and 3D do not give the similar results (flat join segment line). In 3D the segments are not joined. Please help!

```
H = 0.5;
seg = {Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 2 H}}], Disk[{0, H}, 0.1]};
alpha[n_] := (1 + n /10) Pi/20;

Table[Translate[
 Rotate[seg, - 
 Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, n}]], {H (Sin[ Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, n}]] + 
   2 Sum[Sin[Sum[ alpha[j], {j, 0, i}]], {i, 1, n - 1}]), 
H (1 + Cos[ Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, n}]] + 
   2 Sum[Cos[Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, i}]], {i, 1, n - 1}])}], {n,30}];
Graphics[%]
```

[image]

```
H = 0.5;
seg = {Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 H}}], Sphere[{0, 0, H}, 0.1]};
alpha[n_] := (1 + n /10) Pi/20;

Table[Translate[
  Rotate[seg, 
Sum[ alpha[j], {j, 0, n}], {0, 1, 
 0}], {H (Sin[ Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, n}]] + 
   2 Sum[Sin[Sum[ alpha[j], {j, 0, i}]], {i, 1, n - 1}]), 0, 
H (1 + Cos[ Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, n}]] + 
   2 Sum[Cos[Sum[alpha[j], {j, 0, i}]], {i, 1, n - 1}])}], {n, 30}];
Graphics3D[%, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first and fourth usage messages in [the docs for `Rotate[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html) read like so:

> `Rotate[g, θ]`
>     represents 2D graphics primitives or any other objects `g` rotated counterclockwise by `θ` radians about the center of their bounding box.
>
> ...
>
> `Rotate[g, θ, w]`
>   rotates 3D graphics primitives by `θ` radians around the 3D vector `w` anchored at the origin.

which is the reason for the discrepancy.

Thus, you need to specify the center of rotation explicitly (i.e., the *second* and *fifth* usages in the docs) and not count on the defaults if you'll be doing something this elaborate:

```
H = 0.5;
α[n_] := (1 + n/10) π/20;
σ[n_] := Sum[α[j], {j, 0, n}]


With[{seg = {Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 2 H}}], Disk[{0, H}, 0.1]}}, 
     Graphics[Table[
              Translate[Rotate[seg, -σ[n], {0, H}],
                        {H (Sin[σ[n]] + 2 Sum[Sin[σ[i]], {i, 1, n - 1}]),
                         H (1 + Cos[σ[n]] + 2 Sum[Cos[σ[i]], {i, 1, n - 1}])}],
                    {n, 30}]]]
```

[image: 2D]

```
With[{seg = {Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2 H, 0}}, 1./50], Sphere[{0, H, 0}, 0.1]}}, 
     Graphics3D[Table[
                Translate[Rotate[seg, -σ[n], {0, 0, 1}, {0, H, 0}],
                          {H (Sin[σ[n]] + 2 Sum[Sin[σ[i]], {i, 1, n - 1}]), 
                           H (1 + Cos[σ[n]] + 2 Sum[Cos[σ[i]], {i, 1, n - 1}]), 
                           0}],
                      {n, 30}],
                Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}]]
```

[image: 3D]